# Are there any built-in (ie R.android.*) tab icons available for rapid testing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-tabhost

1) Does Android ship with any built-in tab icons to use as placeholders while developing? None of the entries I saw in the `R.android.` stuff looked like a winner, but maybe I missed something... 2) if not, is the following valid?

```
spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("ptSummary").setIndicator("Patient", null).setContent(getIntent());
```

And 3) With setContent, by providing `getIntent()`, what must be in place in that intent for that code to be valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android Team also offers [this icon](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/images/ic_tab_artists_grey.png), in one of their tutorial. You could always save it and use it on every tab.

Alternatively, the `android:drawable` directory is full of little icons and whatnot, I'm sure that for testing you'd be able to use these. You can easily refer to these in your xml files like so :

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
```